# Pusher Error:Auth Info required to subscribe to private channel

Tags: javascript, websocket, laravel-5, webhooks, pusher

I am using Pusher to make a chat app and in this app I want to show user's activity,i.e, who is Online.I subscribe to a private channel and send authentication `POST` request to my API through the default `(/pusher/auth)` endpoint.I am using Laravel in my Api/backend.I have successfully authenticated the channel for the client.My response status code is `200` and in my response I am receiving my `auth key` `{"auth":"349a141376483e4b0639:9bcc630ec8c5981acbc49ee145dd76031348b533c16fce68ecff70d1a0243a09"}`.But my problem Is how can I get the Information whether the channel is Occupied or Vacated.I have tried to get that,but I am getting

**Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Auth info required to subscribe to private-1"}}}**

Js Code:

```
<script src="//js.pusher.com/3.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
var pusher = new Pusher("****************");//Using default endpoint
var user_id={{Auth::user()->id}};
var user_channel=pusher.subscribe( 'private-' + user_id);//user_id is 1.
 </script>
```

Api Code:

```
public function pusherAuth(Request $request){

 $channel=$request->input("channel_name");
 $socketId = $request->input('socket_id');
 $auth = $this->pusher->socket_auth($channel, $socketId);
 $info=$this->pusher->get_channel_info($channel);
 $channel_occupied = $info->occupied; //trying to get the Channel status.
 return response()->json($channel_occupied); 
}
```

I also tried Webhooks for pusher and set a Webhook url and set the type to Channel existence.What I have understood from the documentation,that **Pusher will send a channel_occupied event whenever any channel becomes occupied (i.e. there is at least one subscriber).**.But how can I grave that event,will it work like the other event,such as Laravel built-in event?.Like This example-

```
     use App\Events\TalkEvent;
     public function Eventdispatcher(){
     event(new TalkEvent($somedata)); 
     }
```

Comment: Are you using `auth_endpoint` instead of `authEndpoint` when you subscribe?

Comment: Sir,I am using the right syntax,If not,how am I getting the formdata?

Comment: Please could you show what you are passing in when you call `var pusher = new Pusher("****************");`?

Comment: Well,It's now solved.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer to this question in case someone experiences the same problem?

Comment: It's nothing,my webhook endpoint was not posting properly due to an internal error.After,I make a correction It's working properly.

Comment: what correction you made? @AsmArman

Comment: What I have done is   returning the $auth variable.Then the channel will be occupied and information of occupied or vacated channel can be retrieve from web hook endpoint.